# Python use last x lines

Tags: python

I've got script to read data from Arduino and save it as TXT file. I also have script to separate data and to add date/time, than save in new TXT file.

I've got also few Cron scripts like:

- Read temeprature every 1 minute and save as TXT file (Script 1)
- Read temperature every 10 minutes and save as TXT file (Script 2)
- Read temperature every 60 minutes and save as TXT file (Script 3)

I would like to make a few charts:

- Temperature in last hour
- Temperature in last 3 hours
- Temperature in last 12 hours
- Temperature in last 24 hours
- Temperature in last 7 days

So I need new Python script to:

- Get last 60 lines from Script 1 - save it as new TXT file, to use it as chart "Temperature in last hour"
- Get last 18 lines from Script 2 - save it as new TXT file, to use it as chart "Temperature in last 3 hours"
- Get last 72 lines from Script 2 - save it as new TXT file, to use it as chart "Temperature in last 12 hours"
- Get last 144 lines from Script 2 - save it as new TXT file, to use it as chart "Temperature in last 24 hours"
- Get last 168 lines from Script 3 - save it as new TXT file to use it as chart "Temperature in last 7 days"

Can you help me to write simple script for example to get last 60 lines from FILE.txt and save them as FILE2.txt ? I will edit it for next scripts I need.

EDIT:
I probbably know how to keep my chart files sized as I want (60 lines), but now I would like to ask is it possible to make any script, who will delete FIRST 30 lines?

I have only about 1 GB space, so I need to clean TXT files ;) If I will get temperature every minute after two weeks It will full my hard drive ;)

So I think CRON action to delete first X lines from txt file can help me a lot. Do you know any script?

If I will get it, I will finally finish my master project and ofcourse I will show you results :)

Comment: Here is the simple script to put the last 60 lines of `FILE.txt` in  `FILE2.txt`, considering you're using Linux, Mac OS X or another unix based OS: `tail -n60 FILE.txt > FILE2.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your small program, just run it every one minutes in cron

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from random import randrange
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

#generate random temperature
temperature = randrange(50, 100)

#database structure
structure = "{'last_hour': [], 'last_3_hours': [], 'last_12_hours': [], " \
            "'last_24_hours': [], 'last_7_days': []}"

#file for the database
database = 'temperature_database.txt' #use absolute path when running from cron

#check database file exists, if not write the database structure
try:
    with open(database): pass
except IOError:
    with open(database, 'w') as handler:
        handler.write(structure)

#read the contents of the database
with open(database, 'r') as handler:
    db_contents = eval(handler.read())

#first save every minute
db_contents['last_hour'].append(temperature)
if len(db_contents['last_hour']) > 60:
    db_contents['last_hour'] = db_contents['last_hour'][-60:] #get the last 60 elements

if now.minute in [10, 0]: #every ten minutes
    db_contents['last_3_hours'].append(temperature)
    if len(db_contents['last_3_hours']) > 18:
        db_contents['last_3_hours'] = db_contents['last_3_hours'][-18:]

    db_contents['last_12_hours'].append(temperature)
    if len(db_contents['last_12_hours']) > 72:
        db_contents['last_12_hours'] = db_contents['last_12_hours'][-72:]

    db_contents['last_24_hours'].append(temperature)
    if len(db_contents['last_24_hours']) > 144:
        db_contents['last_24_hours'] = db_contents['last_24_hours'][-144:]

if now.minute == 1: #every hour
    db_contents['last_7_days'].append(temperature)
    if len(db_contents['last_7_days']) > 168:
        db_contents['last_7_days'] = db_contents['last_7_days'][-168:]

#save the contents to the database
with open(database, 'w') as handler:
    handler.write(str(db_contents))
```

After four minutes the file contains

```
{'last_hour': [62, 99, 83, 71], 'last_12_hours': [], 'last_24_hours': [], 'last_3_hours': [], 'last_7_days': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tail` recipe from [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-recipes) here:

```
from collections import deque

def tail(filename, n=10):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return deque(f, n)

lines = tail("script",18)
```

Comment: Yes but this is not good for huge files since you are still iterating through the whole file, although it is very elegant

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of glenbot's idea :

```
import os

def tail(f, n=1, _buffer=1):
    """Tail a file and get X lines from the end"""
    # place holder for the n found
    lines = []

    block_counter = -1

    while True:
        try:
            f.seek(block_counter * _buffer, os.SEEK_END)
        except IOError:  # either file is too small, or too many n requested
            f.seek(0)
            return f.readlines()

        lines = f.readlines()

        # we found enough, get out
        if len(lines) > n:
            return lines[-n:]

        # decrement the block counter to get the next X bytes
        block_counter -= 1
```